# Extra Line is being printed

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interenet_service_provider {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String package_chosen;
        int hours_used = 0;
        int additional_hours = 0;
        double additional_charge = 0;
        double package_a = 9.95;
        double package_b = 13.95;
        double package_c = 19.95;
        int pack_a_time_lim = 10;
        int pack_b_time_lim = 20;
        double pack_a_addtional_fee = 2.00;
        double pack_b_addtional_fee = 1.00;
        double totalBill = 0;
        
        System.out.println("What package do you have?");
        package_chosen = scanner.nextLine();
        
        switch (package_chosen)
        {
        case ("c"):
            System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + package_c + " per month.");
            break;
        case ("a"):
            System.out.println("How many hours of internet did you use?");
            hours_used = scanner.nextInt();
            
            if (hours_used <= 10); 
            {
                System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + package_a + " per month.");
            }
            if (hours_used > 10);
            {
            additional_hours = hours_used - pack_a_time_lim; 
            additional_charge = additional_hours * pack_a_addtional_fee;
            totalBill = package_a + additional_charge;
    
            System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + totalBill);
            }
            break;
            }
        }
}
```

This is my code, I am not done but I ran into the following issues:
inside the case statemen I can type 'if' but recieve an error when I type else. And if I do just put If twice then bothe statements print instead of one

i.e

```
What package do you have?
a
How many hours of internet did you use?
11
Your bill amounts to $9.95 per month. **HOW DO I REMOVE THIS LINE**
Your bill amounts to $11.95
```

I tried doing next.Line to skip a line but when I do that only the first statement prints,
"Your bill amounts to $9.95 per month." But in my case I want only the second statement to print

Comment: You have a semicolon after your if statement. Or to be more precise: Your if statements have empty bodies.

Comment: @tgdavies I agree it's the same, algol-derived syntactical concept. But surely the best available duplicate for a question motivated by a semicolon after `if` in Java, is not a question motivated by a `for` loop in C?

Comment: It was the best one I found. But perhaps I should have looked harder.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (hours_used <= 10);
{
// invalid if block
}
```

This is an invalid if block. The if block either ends at the first closing } (of the block) or the first ';' which is not in the if-block, depending on what comes first.

EDIT: Technically, it isn't an if block, though it might seem to be one. As the if- ended at the first ';' encountered after the if statement, your code is identical to:

```
if ( hours_used <= 10 ) {} // empty body of the if block
{
  // your block
}
```

Remove all those ';'s at the end of your if statements:

```
if (hours_used <= 10)
{
// valid if block
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: Is 'invalid' the right way to describe it? The first example is an if statement with an empty body, followed by a code block. Nothing invalid about it, it just does something different from what was expected.

Comment: @tgdavies seeing as it technically isn't even an if block ...
As you said yourself, it just might look like an if block, and the OP treats it as such, but it's wrong to use it as such (wrong if block would be more confusing compared to invalid)

Comment: @tgdavies which word fits better?

Comment: I think I'd say: The code block containing the `println` is not associated with the if condition, because the body of the if statement is the empty statement produced by the semicolon.

Comment: @user85421 indeed, will update that.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... inside the case statemen I can type 'if' but recieve an error when I type else. ..."*

This is because you've ended the *if-statement* with a semi-colon.

```java
if (hours_used > 10);
{
    additional_hours = hours_used - pack_a_time_lim;
    additional_charge = additional_hours * pack_a_addtional_fee;
    totalBill = package_a + additional_charge;

    System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + totalBill);
}
```

The following *Java* tutorial outlines the *if* and *else-if* structure syntax.
*[The if-then and if-then-else Statements (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)*.

Here is a re-factor.

```java
switch (package_chosen) {
    case "c" -> {
        System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + package_c + " per month.");
    }
    case "a" -> {
        System.out.println("How many hours of internet did you use?");
        hours_used = scanner.nextInt();
        
        if (hours_used <= 10)
            System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + package_a + " per month.");
        if (hours_used > 10) {
            additional_hours = hours_used - pack_a_time_lim;
            additional_charge = additional_hours * pack_a_addtional_fee;
            totalBill = package_a + additional_charge;

            System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + totalBill);
        }
    }
}
```

> *"... Your bill amounts to $9.95 per month. **HOW DO I REMOVE THIS LINE** ..."*

You're referring to the first *if-statement*.

```java
if (hours_used <= 10)
    System.out.println("Your bill amounts to $" + package_a + " per month.");
```